# Problem 3-35(b) in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak. Please tell me how to complete (b) using the author's hint.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, volume, rectangles

> Problem 3-35
> (a) Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation of one of the following types:
> $$\begin{cases}
> g(e_i)=e_i & i\neq j \\
> g(e_j)=ae_j &
> \end{cases}$$
> $$\begin{cases}
> g(e_i)=e_i & i\neq j \\
> g(e_j)=e_j+e_k &
> \end{cases}$$
> $$\begin{cases}
> g(e_k)=e_k & k\neq i,j\\
> g(e_i)=e_j &\\
> g(e_j)=e_i &
> \end{cases}$$
> If $U$ is a rectangle, show that the volume of $g(U)$ is $|\det g|\cdot v(U)$.
> (b) Prove that $|\det g|\cdot v(U)$ is the volume of $g(U)$ for any linear transformation $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. *Hint:* If $\det g\neq 0$, then $g$ is the composition of linear transformations of the type considered in (a).

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation.
Let $g=g_m\circ g_{m-1}\circ\cdots\circ g_1$, where each $g_i$ is a linear transformation of one of the three types in (a).
Let $i=\min\{j:g_j\text{ is a linear transformation of the second type in (a).}\}$.
$v(g_1(U))=|\det g_1|\cdot v(U)$.
$g_1(U)$ is also a rectangle.
So, $v(g_2(g_1(U)))=|\det g_2|\cdot v(g_1(U))=|\det g_2|\cdot |\det g_1|\cdot v(U)$.
$\cdots$
$v((g_{i-1}\circ\cdots\circ g_1)(U))=|\det g_{i-1}|\cdot\cdots\cdot |\det g_1|\cdot v(U)=|\det (g_{i-1}\circ\cdots\circ g_1)|\cdot v(U)$.
But $g_i((g_{i-1}\circ\cdots\circ g_1)(U))$ is not a rectangle.
So, we cannot continue this calculation using the result (a) anymore.
Please tell me how to complete (b) using the author's hint.

---

Let $U$ be an arbitrary Jordan-measurable set.
I guess if $g$ is the first type in (a), then we can show $v(g(U))=|a|\cdot v(U)$.
I guess if $g$ is the third type in (a), then we can show very easily $v(g(U))=v(U)$.
So, if $g_{i+1}$ is the first type in (a) or the third type in (a), then $v((g_{i+1}\circ\cdots\circ g_1)(U))=|\det (g_{i+1}\circ\cdots\circ g_1)|\cdot v(U)$ holds.
But if $g_{i+1}$ is also the second type in (a), $\cdots$.

Comment: One approach is to prove (a) for arbitrary regions. Actually it is simpler to prove (a) for smooth compactly supported functions and then use a density argument to obtain (a) and (b) in full generality. It's best to use measure theory for the generality.

Comment: @Mason thank you very much for your answer. Let $\Phi:x\mapsto Px+b$ be an affine transformation. When $A$ is Jordan-measurable, $\Phi(A)$ is also Jordan-measurable and $\mu(\Phi(A))=|\det P|\mu(A)$ holds. After reading your answer, I tried to find more general result in calculus books. And I found this theorem in "Calculus II" (in Japanese) by Shizuo Miyazima. I will read the proof. I will learn measure theory after reading "Calculus on Manifolds". Thank you very much.

Comment: See page 96 of http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf for a proof.

Comment: @Mason thank you very much for your reference. I will read the proof of Proposition 3.1.10.